# Userland proxy error when launching docker image on Google Cloud Platfrom

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run a standard nginx container on one of my GCP VMs. When i run

```
docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6
```

I get the following error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
```

However it is a clean VM instance I created. During VM creation I also checked the http port to make sure port 80 is open (i need to add https - but this is my first deployment test).

The image does work locally. It seems to be a Google Cloud Platform configuring thing I guess.

Answer (score 2):

it was my own stupid error.. sorry for asking the SO community... 
so what did I do wrong.. I connected through the web client.. which means port 80 is already in use. causing all this havoc :(

so just ssh in and try again and it works.

Comment: Had the same problem. Just sshed via web client on other port and it solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I  tried to reproduce the issue on my end, but I did not find any error. Here are the below steps I have taken.

1. First I spin up a Debian vm instance in the Google cloud platform and allowed incoming http in the firewall for that VM instance so that I could access the site from outside.
2. Then I installed docker in the VM instance. I followed [this link](https://gist.github.com/upbeta01/3b968320b3a579c326ab6cd2a195b10d).
3. After that, I made sure that http port is free in the VM instance. I used the below command.
   netstat -an | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'
   You may check the link [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/357323/how-can-i-list-my-open-ports-on-debian).
4. At this point, I issued the docker command you provided.
   docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6

I did not get any error and I could access the nginx page.

“Hello World from Flask in a uWSGI Nginx Docker container with Python 3.6 (default)”

If you spin a new VM with the same docker version, do you have the same issue? What kind of image is your VM running?